# How can I compute the result of the magnitude of edges of an image?

Tags: image-processing, image-restoration

I have a random image with 11x11 pixels. In the center of the image is a square of 5x5 pixels. The gray level of the background is 0 and the gray level of the square is 50. How can I compute the result of the magnitude of edges given by the compass operator for this image taking into account that the image is not noisy?

Comment: Is this a homework/exam question?

Comment: @MBaz none of them.